# How to definitively align vertically and centrally with the bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried a lot before creating this doubt, but I didn't find anything like that, I can't align a div vertically with the bootstrap, how can I do this?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container text-center p-5">
  <h1 style="font-family: 'Montez', cursive; font-size: 100px;">Nome</h1>
  <p style="font-family: 'Montserrat'; font-size: 20px;">Dev</p>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 rounded-pill font-weight-bold">PORTFÓLIO</a>
  <div class="mt-4">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[It is not elegant](https://jsfiddle.net/bm1c4xwg/), but will work.

СSS:

```
.container{
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css :

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="inner"/>
</div>
```

where child is :

```
.parent {
  display : flex;
  align-items : center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aligning an element vertically is made very easy with flexbox. Use the class `d-flex` on the `.col` element inside the `.row` so it is displayed via `display:flex`. The class `.flex-column` forces the content to be flexed in a vertical way. `.justify-content-center` centers the element vertically. I applied a height of `300 px` to the `.col` so you can see the effect.

You asked about centering it vertically. If you want to center it horizontally too, simply add `align-items-center` as a class to the `col` like so:

```
col bg-light d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center
```

```css
.col {
  min-height:300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="col bg-light d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
      <h1>Nome</h1>
  </div>
      
</div>
```